# how do you display a variable in a text field? AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, action

I am new to AS3 and I have been creating myself mini-projects to learn and my newest one is to have a variable that counts up.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 0; i++)
{
    trace (i);
}
```

I have a dynamic text field that 
I am trying to display the variable i in a dynac text field. How would I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
txtField.text = i.toString();
```

or

```
txtField.text = String(i);
```

Comment: @SamRichard Don't forget to mark the question as answered if it solved your problem :)